# PHP design patterns

Tags: шаблоны-проектирования, php

Помогите разобраться с паттернами *php*. Имеется базовый абстрактный класс, который задает методы поведения объекта. Например, `class Field`.

```
abstract class Field
{
    static function getInstance($instance)
    {
        return new $instance;
    }
    abstract function createField();
}
```

В скрипте нужно создать объект, который будет наследоваться от этого базового класса и задавать свое поведение, в зависимости от наследника.

```
class TextField extends Field
{
    protected function createField()
    {
         return 'textfield';
    }
}

class SelectField extends Field
{
    protected function createField()
    {
         return 'selectfield';
    }
}
```

При этом мне нужно в базовом классе как-то сохранять значение текущего созданного объекта. Что-то вроде синглтона надо создать, чтобы я мог после инициализации `Field::createInstance('SelectField')` в любой момент знать, какой объект сейчас используется.
Подскажите, какой лучше всего паттерн использовать, либо может подтолкните на мысль, как это реализовать?

Comment: быть может Observer вам поможет

Comment: Как-то слишком сумбурно все это...

Что означает ваше 

    Field::createInstance('SelectField')

и где описание этого метода?

Вы, кстати, в него уже передаете `SelectField`. По все видимости объект этого класса и будет использоваться.

Если же вы хотите через родителя получить конкретный объект потомка, то вряд ли вы где-то найдете такое решение. Попробуйте использовать коллекции (или массивы на крайняк), или тот же синглтон, если такой объект может быть только один.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
    abstract class Field
    {
        static $childType = null;

        function __construct($type) {
            if (!is_null($type)) {
                self::$childType = $type;
            }
        }

        static function getInstance($instance)
        {
            return new $instance;
        }
        abstract protected function createField();
    }

    class TextField extends Field
    {
        function __construct() {
            parent::__construct(__CLASS__);
        }

        protected function createField()
        {
            return 'textfield';
        }
    }

    class SelectField extends Field
    {
        function __construct() {
            parent::__construct(__CLASS__);
        }

        protected function createField()
        {
            return 'selectfield';
        }
    }

    $TextField = new TextField();
    echo Field::$childType . "<br/>\n";

    $SelectField = new SelectField();
    echo Field::$childType . "<br/>\n";
?>
```